# Disable variable-length automatic arrays in gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I couldn't disable it even though by using `-std=c89` flag. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can generate an error for variable length arrays using a compiler flag:

```
-Werror=vla
```

Answer (score 2):

> [Variable-length arrays in C89?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159746/variable-length-arrays-in-c89)
>
> GCC always supported variable length arrays AFAIK. Setting -std to C89
>   doesn't turn off GCC extensions ...

See also:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC76

Finally,

> http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html
>
> '-pedantic' and other options cause warnings for many GNU C
>   extensions. You can prevent such warnings within one expression by
>   writing `__extension__` before the expression. `__extension__` has no
>   effect aside from this.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted. The question was how to disable VLAs. @cauon's answer is the correct one.

Comment: It almost looks like the answer was written by some type of automated bot that just looks up random links and quotes related to the search term.