# concatenate string_views in constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, string-view

I'm trying to concatenate `string_views` in a `constexpr`.
The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

// concatenate two string_views by copying their bytes
// into a newly created buffer
constexpr const std::string_view operator+
    (const std::string_view& sv1, const std::string_view& sv2)
{
    char buffer[sv1.size()+sv2.size()] = {0};
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sv1.size(); i++)
        buffer[i] = sv1[i];
    for(size_t i = sv1.size(); i < sv1.size()+sv2.size(); i++)
        buffer[i] = sv2[i-sv1.size()];
    return std::string_view(buffer, sv1.size()+sv2.size());
}

int main()
{
    const std::string_view sv1("test1;");
    const std::string_view sv2("test2;");
    std::cout << sv1 << "|" << sv2 << ": " << (sv1+sv2+sv1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "test1;"sv << "|" << "test2;"sv << ": " <<
        ("test1;"sv+"test2;"sv) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However this code does not produce the result I expected. Instead of printing `test1;test2;test1` and `test1;test2;` it prints out correct characters mixed with random characters as if I'm accessing uninitialized memory.

```
test1;|test2;: F��<��itest;
test1;|test2;: est1;te`�i
```

However if I remove the `constexpr` specifier and replace the `string_views` with `strings` the above code prints the expected output.

```
test1;|test2;: test1;test2;test1;
test1;|test2;: test1;test2;
```

Either I'm missing some obvious mistake in my code or there is something about `constexpr` that I don't understand (yet). Is it the way I'm creating the buffer for the new `string_view`? What else could I do? Or is what I'm trying to do impossible? Maybe there is someone who can shed light to this for me.

Comment: You cannot concatenate *references*. And `string_view` is a reference type.

Comment: `char buffer[sv1.size()+sv2.size()]` is not standard C++. VLA is an extension. (function arguments are not constexpr).

Comment: @Jarod42, actually, `std::string_view::size()` being constexpr means that as long as the function is called with constexpr arguments, this is actually fine. That should be enforced with a local constexpr variable,of course, but I believe his specific example is actually ok.

Comment: @Frank: `sv1` is not constexpr (and we don't have way to express that currently). so `sv1.size()` is not `constexpr`.

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Jarod42 But why does this compile then? I'm using std=c++17 which shouldn't use gnu extensions.

Comment: Also the whole function is constexpr. The code shouldn't compile anyway if sv1.size() isn't constexpr, should it?

Comment: You got warning with correct flag: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/678722075ab41345). See also [disable-variable-length-automatic-arrays-in-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710642/disable-variable-length-automatic-arrays-in-gcc)

Comment: Ah thanks. Didn't know that.

Comment: As its name implies `string_view` is not for holding and returning *data* it is for looking at someone else's data. So it has to be looking at data that actually exists. After your function exits the data that the `string_view` is looking at (a local array) gets destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task is fundamentally impossible, since `string_view`, by definition, needs to have continuous **non-owning** storage from start to finish. So it'll be impossible to manage the lifetime of the data.

You need to create some kind of `concatenated_string<>` custom range as your return type if you want to do something like this.

As to the specific reason your code is yielding weird results, it's simply because `buffer` does not exist anymore when the function exits.

Comment: Ah it seems possible ... here is the design '  template<char...  str0, char...  str1>
  inline
   constexpr
   string<str0..., str1...>
   operator+(string<str0...>, string<str1...>)
  {
   return {};
  }'  just please implement the string<char ...> and implement transforming from std::string_view into it :)

Answer (score 2):

In `return std::string_view(buffer, sv1.size()+sv2.size());` the returned `string_view` views the `buffer` which goes out of scope, so you essentially have a dangling reference.