# Expression must have a constant value error in array via MPI world size

Tags: visual-studio, mpi

Recently, i started learning about MPI programming and I have tried to program it on both Linux and Windows OS. I do not have any problem running the MPI application on Linux, however, i stumbled upon `expression must have a constant value error` on Visual Studio

For example, i'm trying to get the `world_size` via the `MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);` and create an array based on the `world_size` (for example)

Code Sample :

```
#include <mpi.h>
      int world_size;
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

      int database[world_size]; //error occured here
```

However, when i'm running it on Linux, it is working perfectly fine as i'm able to execute the code while stating the number of processes i wish to have. Am i missing out anything? I followed this particular [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYlJc9REY60&t=226s) that taught me how to install MS-MPI on my Visual Studio 2015.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic array sizing using non const values actually works with gcc (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). However, it's considered a bad idea because (as you've just experienced) your code won't be portable anymore. You just need to change your code to create an array using `new`. You might want to generate an error to make sure your code is portable: [Disable variable-length automatic arrays in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710642/disable-variable-length-automatic-arrays-in-gcc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. Finally got an answer after googling for several hours.