# program ends after for loop in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop

### why does this program run only till the first for loop and then stops?

It doesn't run the second *for* loop and also skips *system("pause")*. Can anyone explain what is wrong in my code?
I want to make two arrays of strings: *strgs1* and *strgs2* of length *a* and *b*, and then take the input from the user for each element of the arrays.
This is my code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a,b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    string strgs1[a-1], strgs2[b-1];
    
    for(int i = 0;i < a;i++){
        cin>>strgs1[i];
    }        
    for(int j = 0;j < b;j++){
        cin>>strgs2[j];
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `string strgs1[a-1]` Not to mention, that VLAs are non-standard C++, the last index your loops try to access is `a-1`, which is out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. `strgs1[a-1]` has `a-1` elements numbered `0` through `a-2`. The loop attempts to access an element at index `a-1` - there's no such element.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius why is strgs[a-1] out of bounds?? the for loops condition is i < a so it will iterate till i = a-1.

Comment: @firangi *why does this program run* -- That program should fail to compile, let alone run.  `string strgs1[a-1], strgs2[b-1];` -- That is not C++.

Comment: A program with UB may do *anything*. Don't write UB.

Comment: @firangi For laughs, enter a negative number for `a` and `b`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie my minGW compiler g++ gives no error for this program

Comment: @firangi -- It isn't C++.  That compiler is using VLA's (Variable Length Arrays), which is an *extension*, but isn't real C++.  If you compiled with different compiler options, you will see your code will no longer compile.  Stop using it and use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you mean I should not use minGW for C++? `std::vector` is just a datatype no?. and btw the program is compiling.

Comment: @firangi mingW uses `g++`.  The `g++` compiler *by default* allows such syntax.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31710642/disable-variable-length-automatic-arrays-in-gcc) to turn off this option.  This is one complaint I have with `g++` -- it lets new programmers believe they are writing valid C++ with this VLA stuff.  I wish the people that maintain that compiler would just turn VLA's *off* by default (and let all programmers know that version (whatever) will no longer, by default, support VLA's).

Comment: @firangi "_why is strgs[a-1] out of bounds??_" The last element of `strgs` has index of `a-2`.

Comment: @firangi "my minGW compiler g++ gives no error for this program" - Compilers are *not* required to emit warnings or errors for undefined behaviour (or many other forms of broken programs). You *cannot* rely on "it compiles" as a test for "valid program".

Comment: the compiler just skips everything after the for loop. so what is the right way to do this? @JesperJuhl I am not using a debugger.

Comment: @firangi As some of us (including the answers) already stated: You are iterating out-of-bounds of your array. That is undefined behavior.

Comment: @firangi where did I mention a debugger?

Comment: In case you did not catch it earlier; "undefined behaviour" means "bug in your program" where the compiler is allowed to do *whatever it pleases*. So *any* behaviour you observe is allowed. The solution is to fix your broken code to *not* contain UB.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius How is it out-of-bounds it will iterate till i = a-1 hence it will reach strgs1[a-1]. do you also mean VLA?

Comment: @Jesper Juhl you didn't say debugger but isn't that what a debugger does?
just tell me the right code someone...

Comment: @firangi [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JesperJuhl my program isn't running as I expected it to. How would you write this program?

Comment: I get that. Which is why you ought to a) learn the language. b) use a debugger. And just spoon-feeding you code is not going to teach you anything, so no, I'm not going to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point, you are using static arrays `string strgs1[a-1], strgs2[b-1];` with sizes non-constant at compile time. That's a bad idea. I would advice to use std::vector instead.

Second point, the sizes that you are using for your arrays are not good. For example, the size of your first array is `a-1` and you try to insert `a` strings inside it (from 0 to a-1).

Comment: "That's a bad idea" - not just a bad idea. Such arrays are *not* valid C++ at all. Some compilers implement VLAs as an extension, but it's *not* valid according to the standard and *will* break on other compilers.

Comment: I thought array size also starts from 0 that's why I wrote strgs1[a-1]. Now the code is working thanks! I don't know std::vector I will learn it. 
now the question seems very stupid..lol

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you enter a=3. The size of the array is a-1=2. The loop iterates i=0, i=1, i=2. But this is 3 elements, while your vector has only size 2!

Furthermore, use std::vector. Arrays with non constant size are allowed by some compilers, but it is not portable.